# Resources on installation of Android app

Tags: android

When android app is installed, does it keep only the resources required by the device current configuration (resolution, language etc) and remove all other redundant resources?

(What will be the point of keeping high resolution images when it won't use it ever?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever files you have in your APK will be persistent. it will not get deleted by any chance.

As far as I know, the idea is to make use of a single APK to be compatible with the different types of Android devices available. It is not a good practice to design different apk for different Devices.

But yes, some of your resources will never be used by the device and this is how it works.

if required you can create multiple apks for a single app itself.

And it is well explained here,

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is all compiled in one apk file, so no choice. It will keep all the resources.